# Trying to splice several words inside of a string

Tags: javascript

I'm an absolute beginner with javascript and need someone to hold my hand. I have a string that I am trying to splice several words out of, and need help doing so. It's probably easier if I use an example:

**What I have**:

> "Testing::testing2::testing3 Sample::sample2::sample3"

**What I want spliced out**:

> "testing3 sample3"

The code that I am using right now will only display the last word (sample3), but I need it to show the last word before the 'space' in both sequences.
Help?

**Current code:**

```
var the_string = "Testing::testing2::testing3 Sample::sample2::sample3";
var parts = the_string.split('::').slice(-1);
document.getElementById('tagslast').innerHTML = parts;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the string by a space, then split each individual item by `::` and get the last items:

```js
const str = "Testing::testing2::testing3 Sample::sample2::sample3";

const result = str.split(" ").map(e => e.split("::").slice(-1)[0])

console.log(result)
```